# How to do arithmetic group by quarter mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which have not relation both of them.

```
Table of income
Id      Category    Nominal    Description         Date
----    --------    --------    --------         --------
1         ADD         10000           Q1        2020-03-05
2         DD          15000           Q2        2020-05-11
3         PAD          5000           Q3        2020-08-10

Table of outcome
Id      Category    Nominal    Description         Date
----    --------    --------    --------         --------
1         ADD          7000           Q1        2020-03-20
2         DD          10000           Q2        2020-06-02
3         PAD          2000           Q3        2020-08-28
```

So, I want to do subtraction of nominal from income with nominal from outcome group by quarter.

Here is my query :

```
CREATE view Total AS
    SELECT QUARTER(outcome.date) AS Qperiod, income.nominal-outcome.nominal AS remain
    FROM income, outcome
    GROUP BY YEAR(outcome.date), QUARTER(outcome.date)
```

this result shown below, it describe that first row in income table subtraction by all outcome nominal.

```
Qperiod    remain    
----      -------- 
1             3000
2                0
3             8000
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL have limited access to any underlying indexes, rendering them of questionable  usefulness

Comment: Also, including arithmetic operators in table/column identifiers is seriously ill-advised

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani expected output was answered by Nick

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Strawberry I just use it for check the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `JOIN` condition in your query, so each row of `income` gets matched to every row of `outcome`. Since you have no aggregation function, this effectively means that a random row from `outcome` is subtracted from each row of `income`. You should use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax and put in the appropriate `JOIN` condition, which is that the year and quarter are the same in both tables:

```
CREATE view Total AS
    SELECT QUARTER(outcome.date) AS Qperiod, income.nominal-outcome.nominal AS remain
    FROM income
    JOIN outcome ON YEAR(outcome.date) = YEAR(income.date)
                AND QUARTER(outcome.date) = QUARTER(income.date)
    GROUP BY YEAR(outcome.date), QUARTER(outcome.date)
```

Output:

```
Qperiod     remain
1           3000
2           5000
3           3000
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c8904/1)